# preconditioning least square in python?

Tags: python, linear-solver, least-squares, preconditioning

For a nonsymmetric matrix, we can solve { A^T @ A x = A^T b } by lsqr or cgls or something else. Usually it will be slow, so we need a preconditioner either ilu, multigrid or something else. Is there any good source for comparison of different preconditioners with python implementation? And what combination of solver/preconditioner is currently used for a typical problem like 2d Poisson problem in practice now? Thanks.